How to see what has changed in the currently open modified file?
If you have a file open in the editor, and it shows the black dot in the tab, it means you have changed something. How do you find out what has changed in the open editor?
If you save it, you may be saving an accidental keystroke so break the build. If you don't save it, you might not be saving a fix you did an hour ago.
VS Code has no "compare to what is on disk" function.
There is a "timeline" tab, which for me shows the last git commit. I can select this file for comparison, but there is no way to compare it with the currently open file. If you double click on it, it compares it to previous commit, not to what's open in editor.
The only thing I can think of is to make a backup of the original file, save the modified file, the do a diff, then delete the unwanted one. Several times I have done this to find there are no differences!
Is there a built-in way to do this, ideally without resorting to 3rd party plugins?

Yes, that one gives the answer - thanks!
